# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage Hides UIBarButtonItem on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

On a few child views of a navigation controller, I have different Navigation Bar Images, so I use:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIImage *gradientImage46 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar2.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:gradientImage46 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

On iOS 7 and above, this works fine.  However, on iOS 6, it hides the Back Button.  Thoughts?  It's not just hidden, pressing the area does nothing